How to link a dynamic cell from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2
I have here Sheet 1 that has an ID number I enetered manually.
Sheet1

What I would like to do with this ID number is to link to Sheet 2 selecting the same ID number/s. Whenever I click on the ID number of Sheet 1, it will automatically show Sheet 2 selecting the cell/s of the same ID number/s I clicked on Sheet 1. Sheet 2 may have duplicates and it should select the same IDs. If there's no duplicate, then it should just select one cell of the same ID.
Sheet2

What I only know is to use the link function of Excel to go to Sheet 2 which does only show the whole Sheet 2.
Sheet 1 Linking to Sheet 2

Help is greatly appreciated.

I think you need to find the address the ID in sheet2 using lookup formula, and then use =HYPERLINK to create a hyperlink in sheet1. https://exceljet.net/functions/hyperlink-function

@rachel yes you may have the idea. i just don't know how to arrange it

This code does it. Invoke it in Worksheet.Change event, then create link is not necessary.
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") Then
  idval = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
  Set datash = Worksheets("Sheet2")
  Set toselect = datash.Range("xx1")    'dummy cell address for Union
  For i = 1 To datash.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    If datash.Range("A" & i) = idval Then
      Set toselect = Union(toselect, datash.Range("A" & i))
    End If
  Next i
 
  Intersect(datash.Range("A:A"), toselect).Parent.Activate
  Intersect(datash.Range("A:A"), toselect).Activate
End If
End Sub



awesome! i put it in SelectionChange so i dont have to double click it esp for locked cells.

It is probably not exactly what you are looking for, but it is the easiest I can think of without involving VBA.
The result:

The limitation of this approach is that it doesn't work well when there are duplicates in sheet2. we have to create two separate hyperlink in this case.
Edited:
For some reason I cannot convert excel table to mark down easily.
So I will type the formulas:
In column C:
Below formula finds the row number of ID in sheet2.
=FILTER(ROW(Sheet2!A2:A100),Sheet1!B2=Sheet2!A2:A100,"")
In column D:
Below finds the address of the ID in sheet2:
=CELL("address",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100,Sheet1!C2))
In column E:
Create hyper link:
=HYPERLINK(D2,$B$2)
Edited again ...(made a mistake in formula in columnD)..corrected.

lemme try, be right back

one great job!!
